# Look up name in a table and retrieve the score from 7 columns down based on the latest location that name was found

Tags: microsoft-excel

Here is an image of the sheet I am working on

[image]

For column T2:T I am trying to create a formula that searches table 1 A1:O for the last game the player has played and retrieve their score, which will always be 7 columns down from the winner and loser and if there is no last game found column T would simply equal columns W for that player. Please let me know if my question is unclear or if you can not see my photo. At the moment I am trying a formula like this

```
=Index(Table1,Match(Q2,D:E,0),0),7)
```

to lookup the names in Q2:Q in the latest row of table1 A1:O, and once it has found that name go 7 columns down and retrieve the score, and if no name or score is found T would equal that players starter points which is found in W.

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       A       |       D       |       E       |       M       |       N       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Match ID    |     Winner    |      Loser    | WinnerOutcome | LoserOutcome  |                              
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       1       |     Kamau     |     Rodknee   |      100      |      150      |                              
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       2       |    Rodknee    |      Kamau    |      200      |      50       |                              
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                                  Table2
------------------------------------------------
       Q       |       T       |       W       |  
------------------------------------------------                         
   Players     |    Points     |Starter Points |                             
------------------------------------------------
     Kamau     |       ?       |       50      |                               
------------------------------------------------
    Rodknee    |       ?       |       200     | 
------------------------------------------------
      Jim      |       ?       |       50      |                                 
-------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: People would be more inclined to help if you pasted your data directly in the post instead of a photo we need to recreate instead of just copy and paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I would create helper columns of standard formula to combine the two together in order.  I placed this in Y2:

```
=INDEX(D:E,QUOTIENT(ROW(1:1)-1,2)+2,MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,2)+1)
```

And this in Z2:

```
=INDEX(M:N,QUOTIENT(ROW(1:1)-1,2)+2,MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,2)+1)
```

And copy down as far as you want, make sure it is far enough to cover every possible length of data.

[image]

Then in S2 we use this array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($Z$2:INDEX(Z:Z,MATCH("ZZZ",Y:Y)),MATCH(2,IF($Y$2:INDEX(Y:Y,MATCH("ZZZ",Y:Y))=P2,1))),V2)
```

Being an array formula we need to note two things:

1. When entering the array formula one must confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode instead of Enter.  If done correctly the Excel will put `{}` around the formula.
2. Array formula calculate exponentially so we want to the limit the references to only those cells that have data in them.  In the above formula we do this with the `$Z$2:INDEX(Z:Z,MATCH("ZZZ",Y:Y))` which sets the first cell as Z2 and the last as the last cell in Z that is in the row that has the last name in Y.

[image]

---

If you really want it in one formula then this will do it:

```
=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(D:D,IF(MAX(INDEX((ROW($D$2:$E$3))*($D$2:$E$3=P2),))=0,-1,MAX(INDEX((ROW($D$2:$E$3))*($D$2:$E$3=P2),))))=P2,INDEX(M:M,MAX(INDEX((ROW($D$2:$E$3))*($D$2:$E$3=P2),))),INDEX(N:N,MAX(INDEX((ROW($D$2:$E$3))*($D$2:$E$3=P2),)))),V2)
```

Or this one works also:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(M:N,MAX(INDEX((ROW($D$2:$E$3))*($D$2:$E$3=P2),)),IF(INDEX(D:D,IF(MAX(INDEX((ROW($D$2:$E$3))*($D$2:$E$3=P2),))=0,-1,MAX(INDEX((ROW($D$2:$E$3))*($D$2:$E$3=P2),))))=P2,1,2)),V2)
```

Though it is entered normally these are still an array formulas and the `$D$2:$E$3` need to be the extent of the data.  You could replace all the `$E$3` with `INDEX(E:E,MATCH("ZZZ",E:E))` or just use the table reference for those two columns.  But either way that reference needs to be limited to the extents of the data and not the full column.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked perfectly Scott, I really appreciate your help.